# Hide or Show alert when user logs in first time ever

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

More in depth explanation :

So when a user logs in the application from another browser except Chrome i have to hide or show an alert Saying that this application works best in Chrome , and this alert has 2 options , "Don't show me again" and "Ok" which is a button. I've implemented this behaviour to show the div when the user is not in Chrome Browser. So how can i detect if the user is logging in for the first time . Prob is if they click "Don't show me again" which is a checkbox  i should never show this div ever . But if they click "Ok" button the next time they log in this should still show. This is getting me very confused .
I saw some stuff you can do with localstorage but i'm not sure how to do it. Maybe i can store a value on React-redux , but i'm not a specialist on redux aswell and this project files are super big. Need some help.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import styled, { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import { useActions } from '../../Pages/Components/Widget/helpers';
import { ReactComponent as CyabraChrome } from '../../assets/utils/icons/cyabrachrome.svg';
import Checkbox  from '../../facelift/Checkbox/Checkbox'

const isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);

const PageWithSidebar = () => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)
  const [ isOkClicked, setIsOkClicked ] = useState(false)

  const actions = useActions({ list });

  useEffect(() => {
    actions.list();
    const getFirstTimeLogin = async () => {
      const firstTimeLogin = await window.localStorage.getItem('addscan-tooltip-helper')
      if(firstTimeLogin == '0') {
        setShowChromeAlert(true)
      }
    }
    getFirstTimeLogin();
  }, []);

  const handleCheckboxClick = () => {
    setChecked(true)
    setShowChromeAlert(false);
  }

  const handleOkClick = () => {
    setIsOkClicked(true)
  }

  return (
      {!isChrome && showChromeAlert && 
      <AlertDiv style={{ display: isOkClicked ? 'none': ''}}>
        <CyabraChrome />
        <RightDiv>
          <RightDivText>Cyabra Works Better With Chrome </RightDivText>
          <RightDivInner>
              <Checkbox
                checked={checked}
                text="Don't show me again"
                onClick={handleCheckboxClick}
              />
              <ButtonRightDiv onClick={handleOkClick}>
                <RightDivText>Ok</RightDivText>
              </ButtonRightDiv>
          </RightDivInner>
        </RightDiv>  
      </AlertDiv>}
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({});

const mapDispatchToProps = {};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PageWithSidebar);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nice job steve you are doing great bud :), lol

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take the localStorage aproach, at the end of the code set a local storage item to 1, such as:

```
localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', '1');
```

then at the beginning of the code use an if statement such as:

```
   if(localStorage.getItem('loggedIn') == 1) {
alert('This works best in Chrome')
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific , what begging and what end . This is when user Logs in and gets sent to the dashboard

Comment: Lets say you have a statement or a function that activates when the user Logs in, in this function or statement add the second bit of code, this will test if the user already has the localStorage value. Then at the end of your statement/function when the user logs in, add the first bit of code, which will set the localStorage AFTER the test (if statement).

Answer (score -1):

It is impossible to use only the Front area. Use the DB to accurately identify whether the user is exposed to the Alert.

Comment: There is a manipulation you can do with local storage

Comment: @StivenBallshi It is possible to use the same browser and do not clear a cache, but it seems appropriate to use DB because it is difficult to maintain in general.